# AngualrJS input checkbox on mobile not registering correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, input, checkbox

I have an input checkbox within an ng-repeat as follows:

```
<div class="provisions">
    <label ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        <div class="innerProvision">
            <input class="provisionCheck" type="checkbox"
                   ng-model="proValue" ng-change="change(key,proValue)"
                   ng-value="value" ng-click="enable($event,proValue);">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" ng-show="toggle"> </i>
                <i class="fa fa-square-o" ng-hide="toggle"> </i>
            </span>
            <h5> {{value.label}}</h5></li>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

The input is styled as a 100% width by 175px height so that it acts as a button.  I need it as an input for my form data though...

This works great on desktop with no issue.  However on mobile nothing is fired unless I tap constantly until I tap something that fires it (no method of taps, just spastic tapping)...  Any ideas why this is happening / not happening?  I use the ng-change to get the !Boolean.  The ng-click is to trigger a style change.  neither work as they do on desktop.

Help is needed, so any is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just swapped the input for a button and handled the value swap in the controller:

```
<div class="provisions">

        <!--<label ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">-->
            <div class="innerProvision" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
                <button class="provisionCheck" ng-click="enable($event,key);">
                </button>
                <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" ng-show="toggle"> </i>
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o" ng-hide="toggle"> </i>
                </span>
                <h5> {{value.label}}</h5></li>
            </div>
        <!--</label>-->
 </div>
```

controller:

```
someValue = !someValue
```